# dsc-statistics-presenter: Apache2 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache-httpd

I reinstalled a package called dsc-statistics-presenter on my Debian server. It worked fine with my previous installation but now I'm not able to make it work. Error 403, access forbidden. So, let me give you some details.

From `/var/log/`:

```
[Sun Nov 27 17:34:09.186447 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 26682:tid 140497263544064] [client 192.168.1.32:44134] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics/dsc-grapher
```

From the path:

```
root@UKLNDLABDMZ:~# cat /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics/dsc-grapher 
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

use DSC::grapher;
my $grapher = DSC::grapher->new;
$grapher->cgi(new CGI);
$grapher->run();
```

If you want see the file permission:

```
root@UKLNDLABDMZ:~# ls -l /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics/dsc-grapher 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 148 Dec 15  2012 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics/dsc-grapher
```

Only Apache conf installed from the apt-get about that package is the following

```
root@UKLNDLABDMZ:~# cat /etc/apache2/conf-available/dsc-statistics-presenter.conf 
Alias /dsc /usr/share/dsc-statistics-presenter/html
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/dsc-statistics /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics


root@UKLNDLABDMZ:~# ls -ld /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 27 18:41 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics

http://192.168.99.10/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics/dsc-grapher
```

Update:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2
```

and

```
a2enmod cgi
```

The error changed from 403 to 500

Comment: What happens if you call  `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics/dsc-grapher` in the command line? Any errors?

Comment: Added in description

Comment: The error message says: `client denied by server configuration`, and the error comes from `authz_core`. Check your server configuration for any authentification configuration (also look into `.htaccess` file in  `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/dsc-statistics/`).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro
Your suggestion driven my to fix the error. Config file error + lib missing

Comment: Excellent. Would you please then answer your own question?  Do it, and I will edit it slightly if there is a need to further explain what happened. Please, also add to the question, or tag it, with the Debian distribution.